# How to get data from another dataframe based on key values

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have two dataframes

df1

| Area-ID-Series | Area-ID | MODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BSD-1-1800 | BSD-1 | VM |
| BSD-2-1800 | BSD-2 | VM |
| BSD-3-1800 | BSD-3 | VM |
| BSE-1-2100 | BSE-1 | XM |
| BSE-1-900 | BSE-1 | VM |
| BSE-2-2100 | BSE-2 | XM |
| BSE-2-900 | BSE-2 | VM |
| BSE-3-2100 | BSE-3 | XM |
| BSE-3-900 | BSE-3 | VM |
| SMR-1-1800 | SMR-1 | VM |

df2

| Area-ID | 900 | 1800 | 2100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BSD-1 |  |  |  |
| BSD-2 |  |  |  |
| BSD-3 |  |  |  |
| BSE-1 |  |  |  |
| BSE-2 |  |  |  |
| BSE-3 |  |  |  |
| SMR-1 |  |  |  |

df2 has a key based on df1 but without the "Series", because the "Series" transformed into columns.

I want to get MODE value for each series based on Area-ID, so my desired output is like this

df2

| Area-ID | 900 | 1800 | 2100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BSD-1 | - | VM | - |
| BSD-2 | - | VM | - |
| BSD-3 | - | VM | - |
| BSE-1 | VM | - | XM |
| BSE-2 | VM | - | XM |
| BSE-3 | VM | - | XM |
| SMR-1 | - | VM | - |

I have tried this code but still no idea how it should be done

```
df_result = pd.merge(df2,
                    df1[['Area-ID', 'MODE']],
                    on= 'Area-ID',
                    how='left')
```

I have tried to do this in excel with df1 as "city" the formula look like this

900 series column

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&"-"&$B$1,city!A:C,3,0),"-")
```

1800 series column

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&"-"&$C$1,city!A:C,3,0),"-")
```

2100 series column

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&"-"&$D$1,city!A:C,3,0),"-")
```

it worked, but it takes a lot of time because my data is huge so I try to do it with python instead

Comment: Do you really have two data frames or do you just want to transform your df1 to different format?

Comment: I have two data frames, each of it is in different level with different amount of data

Comment: @AlgoRithm is the question still relevant?

Comment: @inquirer yes, still working on the same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know merge very well. Perhaps there is a way to do based on it. Did it differently.

A 'number' column is created. To do this, the rows of the Area-ID-Series column of dataframe df1 are [split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) into an array by delimiter using split and expand=True is applied to get the columns. The second column is retrieved.

Further, the dataframe is grouped by df1.index, that is, it is called on each row, where the expression `df2['Area-ID'] == x['Area-ID'].values[0]` is a mask for indexing rows, and `x[' number'].values[0]` acts as a column name for `df2` filtering. Explicit [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexing is used, where the row indexes are on the left, the column name is on the right.
`.values[0]` is used to extract the value from the list.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', header=0)

df1['number'] = df1['Area-ID-Series'].str.split('-', expand=True)[2].astype(str)


def my_func(x):
    df2.loc[df2['Area-ID'] == x['Area-ID'].values[0], x['number'].values[0]] = x['MODE'].values[0]


df1.groupby(df1.index).apply(my_func)

print(df2)
```

Output

```
  Area-ID  900 1800 2100
0   BSD-1  NaN   VM  NaN
1   BSD-2  NaN   VM  NaN
2   BSD-3  NaN   VM  NaN
3   BSE-1   VM  NaN   XM
4   BSE-2   VM  NaN   XM
5   BSE-3   VM  NaN   XM
6   SMR-1  NaN   VM  NaN
```